# D3 rollup function gives sometime value and sometime values on leaf

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

see the difference

[image]
  [image]

below is the line of code i am creating object.

```
 let TrafficSumDateBasedForSparkline = d3
    .nest()
    .key(function (d) {
      return d.Source;
    })
    .key(function (d) {
      return d.Date;
    })
    .rollup(function (v) {
      return {
        total_session: d3.sum(v, function (d) {
          return d.Session;
        })
      };
    })
    .entries(selectedData);
  return TrafficSumDateBasedForSparkline;
```

it is giving different result on different machine.

Comment: I don't see a difference

Comment: Are there any differences in the set up on the two machines -- different versions of d3?

Comment: one machine is windows and other is linux

Comment: @rioV8 difference is in keyword value and values that contains total_sesseion.

Comment: why mark the whole object when the only thing different is one (1) character in  one (1) word, and in one picture you unfold and the other not

Comment: @vishal may be worth filing a bug report on GitHub